# React Dropzone Uploader Component - How do i change the behavior of the file object onscreen after upload?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am working with react-dropzone-uploader. It is a great little component, but I am new to react and the documentation is a 'little' on the light side. Each file has a 'widget' in the uploader component that shows the status of the upload. Once a file is completed, I want to - after a short delay - change the widget which is a box into a simple text message that says the name of the file and that file upload was complete. I have found how i can remove the widget entirely by using this:

```
    const handleChangeStatus = (file, status) => {
       if (status === 'done') {
         setTimeout(file.remove(), 5000);
       }
    }
```

And that removes the entire widget. But what I want to do is replace at widget with simple text that states:

FilenameXYZ upload completed.

The entire component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'react-dropzone-uploader/dist/styles.css'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone-uploader'

const Standard = () => {
    const getUploadParams = () => {
        return { 
          url: $('#jsVars').attr('data-url'),

        }
    }

    const handleChangeStatus = (file, status) => {
        console.log(status, file)
        if (status === 'done') {
            setTimeout(file.remove(), 5000);
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
        console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
        allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
    }

    return (
        <Dropzone
            getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
            onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            //accept="image/*"
            //inputContent={(files, extra) => (extra.reject ? 'Image files only' : 'Drag Files or click to browse')}
            submitButtonContent="CLEAR"
            styles={{
                dropzoneReject: { borderColor: 'red', backgroundColor: '#DAA' },
                //dropzone: { minHeight: 1000, maxHeight: 1000 } ,
            }}
        />
    )
}

//<Standard />

export default Standard;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Standard />, document.getElementById('standard'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark I would try something like this using conditional rendering.

```
const Standard = () => {
    const [fileStatus, setFileStatus] = useState(null);
    const getUploadParams = () => {
        return { 
          url: $('#jsVars').attr('data-url'),

        }
    }

    const handleChangeStatus = (file, status) => {
        console.log(status, file)
        if (status === 'done') {
            setTimeout(() => {
              /* set the state to the message we want to show */
              setFileStatus(`File ${file.name} uploaded.`);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
        console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
        allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
    }

    /* here we show the fileStatus message if it is set,
       this could also be used for error handling with a
       retry button that sets fileStatus back to null
       and calls file.remove() */
    if(fileStatus) return <div>{fileStatus}</div>

    return (
        <Dropzone
            getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
            onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            //accept="image/*"
            //inputContent={(files, extra) => (extra.reject ? 'Image files only' : 'Drag Files or click to browse')}
            submitButtonContent="CLEAR"
            styles={{
                dropzoneReject: { borderColor: 'red', backgroundColor: '#DAA' },
                //dropzone: { minHeight: 1000, maxHeight: 1000 } ,
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

More info on the topic in the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html